# Socket Programming - TCP Basics

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am trying to implement a program that is able to send TCP packets alone by itself. Ideally I want to send a packet to a port in a computer and have it processed. This means that I am trying to do it without having a client/server files pair.

However, I am finding it really hard to do this as anywhere I look there is mention of both the client and the server files. And if I try to run the client file or the server files by themselves, it doesn't even work as they depend on each other.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: What you want doesn't make sense.

Comment: What good would it do to run the server by itself, with nothing to connect to it? Or to run the client without anything for it to connect to on the other end? If you send data to a port, there has to be a server listening on that port to receive it and do something with it. The port doesn't work on it's own. TCP is not what you're looking for; it's hard to say what the correct solution would be, because you've provided no meaningful details about what you're attempting to accomplish. Google *inter-process communication* plus the OS you're targeting and do some research.

Comment: There is going to have to be some program listening to the port you send the packet to, otherwise the target computer's networking stack will simply drop the packet.  You can use a pre-existing server program (e.g. telnetd or netcat or similar) as the server if you don't want to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do that. But in order to send such packets, you need to use API for IP raw socket (`SOCK_RAW`), instead of TCP.

So you can send IP packets with payload of your "crafted TCP".